# Why are the objects right in front of the light shaded?

Tags: unity-game-engine, light

I am new to unity and am trying to get lighting down. The picture explains it all, for some reason the objects right in front of the wall that is supposed to emit light is shaded.  whatever you need from my project I will post. Appreciate any insight at all

[image]

[image]

I added a picture of some errors I get as well. I am not sure if they are important or not.

Comment: You need to read [ask] and then help by providing a [mcve].

Comment: I know how to use stackoverflow, for unity should I provide my entire package folder? Its not like I can provide a code file that suffices.

Comment: A [mcve] doesn't necessarily mean code. You're asking a fairly vague question. How is it that we can determine what you've done? Please help us to help you.

Comment: Well in all honesty I dont know what you guys would need to help me, thats why I included I will add anything you guys need from me to help you. I do not know anything about unity I apologize. What can I provide that will help you guys better understand?

Comment: @Enigmativity I have not written any code, I am not sure what I could possibly upload. Can you please provide some insight as to what could help better understand my problem?

Comment: Just provide us the steps to replicate your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some of your objets are marked as `static` (top right in the Inspector) and therefore only receive light from light sources or emitting objects that are also marked as `static`.

On the other hand there are also objects that are **not** marked as `static` and therefore these objects will only receive light from light sources that are also **not** marked as `static` (and in specific no light from emitting materials).

See also [Static GameObjects](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StaticObjects.html), [Baked Lighting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LightMode-Baked.html) and [Emissive Materials](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/lighting-emissive-materials.html)

> Emission will only be received by objects marked as ‘Static’ or “Lightmap
> Static’ from the Inspector
> . Similarly, emissive materials applied to non-static, or dynamic geometry such as characters will not contribute to scene lighting.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. I just went and checked and it seems I did make everything static, do I want to click make their children static too? I tried that but still no luck it seems. Would it help if I posted that actual project file?

Comment: @JustinPriede afaik each individual child needs to be `static` yes

Comment: Unfortunately I got no luck there either,Considering I cannot upload my project file and I have not written any code, what can I upload to help you better understand the problem? I think I tried to learn this on too larger of a scale, should have started out smaller. Thank you again for trying to help out tho!